# How does rule engine identify whether the user is anonymous or authenticated user in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8, sitecore7.2

I want to show a different data based on the user role. I had a look at personalization in sitecore and find an option

> “When the current user is a member of specific role”

. I don’t have much idea on how to implement this.

My requirement is that I want to display different carousel images based on the user role. I have 2 different data sources such as unauthenticated users and authenticated users. If the user is anonymous or not logged in then I want to display images from unauthenticated users. If it is registered user or logged in, I want to display images from authenticated user.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have a rule to check if a user is anonymous or not .

Please see below picture :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. how does rules engine identify whether the user is logged in?

Comment: Are you looking for the code? Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore rule Engine cannot identify if the user is logged in or not but you can identify it using Sitecore cookie. This might help you. you can play around personalizing the content. 
https://sitecoresaga.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/recognize-previously-logged-in-visitor-and-apply-personalization/